# PrimeNG p-calendar: change the background-color of the dates

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

Hi I'm trying to customize the `p-calendar` but can't figure out how to change the color of the dates that are being displayed. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

This is my template:

```
<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
    <label for="time">Time</label>
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date7" [showTime]="true" [inline]="true" inputId="time"></p-calendar>

</div>
```

My Css:

```
  ::ng-deep .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-group {
     background-color: whitesmoke;
 }

  
  ::ng-deep .ui-datepicker .ui-widget-content {
     border: 1px solid #888888;
     font-weight: normal;
     color: #000000;
     background-color: red

 }
```

Comment: Which version of PrimeNG do you use?

Comment: I'm on version 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.p-datepicker` instead of `.ui-datepicker`

**CSS**:

```
::ng-deep .p-datepicker table td > span {
  background-color: orange;
}

::ng-deep .p-datepicker table td.p-datepicker-today > span {
  background-color: burlywood;
}
```

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-kp8d1x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)